# Brouwer's fixed point theorem for quotient spaces of the unit ball

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, fixed-point-theorems

Consider the closed unit ball $\overline{\mathbb B ^n}$, and let $\sim$ be some equivalence relation on $\overline{\mathbb B ^n}$ that only identifies points on the boundary $\mathbb S ^{n-1}$ of $\overline{\mathbb B ^n}$, that is, if $x,y\in \overline{\mathbb B ^n}$ are such that $x\sim y$ and $x\neq y$, then $x,y\in \mathbb S ^{n-1}$.

Let $F: \overline{\mathbb B ^n}/\sim \hspace{0.2em}\to \overline{\mathbb B ^n}/\sim$ be a continuous function that sends $\lbrace [x]:x\in \mathbb S ^{n-1}\rbrace$ into itself. Does $F$ have fixed points?

Notice that if $n=1$, then the answer is yes. This is because $\overline{\mathbb B ^1}/\sim$ is homeomorphic to $[-1,1]$ or to a circle; in the first case the result follows by using Brouwer's fixed point theorem and in the second case the result is true simply because $F$ fixes the point in $\overline{\mathbb B ^1}/\sim$ corresponding to the identification of the endpoints of $\overline{\mathbb B ^1}$.

I'm not exactly sure if the result is true in general. I've been trying to adapt Milnor's elementary proof of Brouwer's fixed theorem to this specific case, which is discussed here https://people.math.sc.edu/howard/Notes/brouwer.pdf, but I'm not seeing if this will be fruitful of not.

Does the problem become easier if we assume that $F$ is a homeomorphism that sends $\lbrace [x]:x\in \mathbb S ^{n-1}\rbrace$ onto itself?

Any help or suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: This set $\{[x]\ |\ x\in S^{n-1}\}$ is a singleton. Your relationship collapses boundary to point. And so your condition literally means it is a fixed point of $F$. Also the quotient is homeomorphic to sphere (of dimension $n$), not interval. And so it doesn't have fixed point property in general.

Comment: @freakish In general $\lbrace [x]:x\in \mathbb S ^{n-1}\rbrace$ is not a singleton. It is the set of all equivalence classes of boundary points.

Comment: @freakish notice that it says that the relation only identifies "points on the boundary", and not "all the points on the boundary", so Paul is right. Also, observe that $F$ is required to send $\lbrace [x]: x\in\mathbb S ^{n-1}\rbrace$ into itself, but in the case of a circle that set has only one element, which would necessarily be a fixed point, even though as you say a circle doesn't have the fixed point property in general.

Comment: Note that in the equivalence relation freakish is thinking of, this singleton will be mapped to itself from our assumption, so the map will have a fixed point!

Comment: If $\sim$ identifies anti-podal points then the resulting space is $\text{SO}(3)$ and the equivalence classes corresponding to the sphere are rotations by angle $\pi$. Way to prove $\text{SO}(3)$ has no fixed point property is by considering action of $\text{SO}(3)$ on $\text{SO}(3)$ by left multiplication. But sadly, the only such action which sends rotations by angle $\pi$ to themselves, is the one corresponding to identity matrix. So no counter-example there it seems

Comment: @Jakobian Interesting! I've also been unable to find any counterexamples; I tend to think now that there should always be fixed points, I'm just not sure how to prove it!

Comment: It would be nice if for any continuous $f:\frac{\overline{\mathbb{B}}^n}{\sim}\to \frac{\overline{\mathbb{B}}^n}{\sim}$ sending equivalence classes corresponding to elements of $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ to themselves, there existed continuous $\hat f : \overline{\mathbb{B}}^n \to \overline{\mathbb{B}}^n$ such that $p\circ \hat f = f\circ p$ (i.e. which completes a commutative diagram), since then finding $x$ such that $\hat f(x) = x$ we would get $f(p(x)) = p(x)$ so that $f$ has a fixed point. I suspect it holds under some conditions which makes $p$ into a covering

Comment: @Jakobian I've actually been thinking along those lines too, but I think you now wrote it in a very clear way! The map $p$ would be the quotient map from $\overline{\mathbb B^n}$ to $\overline{\mathbb B^n}/\sim$. To simplify things I'm assuming that $f$ is a homeomorphism that sends $\lbrace [x]:x\in\mathbb S^{n-1}\rbrace$ onto itself, and now I'm trying to come up with $\hat{f}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is false in the general setup, even in very low dimension $2$. I don't know about $F$ being homeomorphism case.

Consider the two dimensional unit disc $B^2=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\ |\ \lVert (x,y)\rVert\leq 1\}$ and take $(x,y)\sim (x,-y)$ for points on the boundary, plus $(-1,0)\sim (0,1)$. This glueing results in a two-dimensional sphere with two points glued (i.e. a torus but with glued hole), and the boundary becomes a small circle. See this picture:

[image]

One of those small circles is the image of $S^1$ under the quotient map. Lets say it is the bottom one.

Now the thing is that each of those circles is a retract of whole space. Indeed, we first retract the upper hemisphere onto the lower (by simply taking $-z$ on $z$ coordinate, after embedding it correctly into $\mathbb{R}^3$), and then squash with rotation until we hit the bottom circle. Like this:

[image]

So this retraction onto the bottom circle together with rotation of the circle will not have a fixed point. Even though it does map the circle onto itself.

Unfortunately this is not a good example if we want $F$ to be a homeomorphism (although it is a homeomorphism on the image of the boundary into itself). Because every self homeomorphism of that space has to map the special glueing point into itself (because it is the only point without euclidean neighborhood), and thus has to be a fixed point.

Comment: Wow, that's a very interesting counterexample!